# Vectorize double loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I am new to R and am trying to vectorize my codes below.

What is a better way to do this? Thanks so much!

*

```
l_mat <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 4))
datax <- data.frame("var1"= c(1,1,1,1), "Var2" = c(2,2,2,2), "Var3"=c(3,3,3,3), "Var4"=c(4,4,4,4))
for (i in 1:4) {
      for (j in 1:4) {
             if (datax[i, 2] == datax[j, 2]) {
                   l_mat[i, j] <- 100
               } else {
                     l_mat[i, j] <- 1
                 }
         }
   }
```

*

Comment: Your condition gives all values to be 100.  Please use a better example

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the logic, @akrun did you?

Comment: it's just a dummy example. In my real example, we'll assign it to a weight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be better done with `outer`.  As we are checking if all the values in the second column against itself, create the logical expression with `outer`, convert it to a numeric index and then replace the values with 1 or 100

```
out <- 1 + (outer(datax[,2], datax[,2], `==`))
out[] <- c(1, 100)[out]
```

---

Or in a single line

```
ifelse(outer(datax[,2], datax[,2], `==`), 100, 1)
```

Or use a variation with `pmax` and `outer`

```
do.call(pmax, list(outer(datax[,2], datax[,2], `==`) * 100, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: in the first asnwer, what does the '+' in front of "(outer" mean?

Comment: @Ketty the output of `outer` is a logical `matrix`.  I meant to `1 +`, sorry.  It is to convert to a numeric index to pass the values 1, 100 where the 1 replaces the 1 and 100 replaces the 2 in the first `out`